# Condition if multiple lists are unique

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I tried searching for an answer but I could not find out a right one.
So let's say I have this:

```
list=['f','f','f','f','r','r','r','r','b','b','b','b','l','l','l','l','t','t','t','t',
      'u','u','u','u']
c1=[list[0],list[13],list[18]]
c2=[list[1],list[4],list[19]]
c3=[list[5],list[8],list[17]]
c4=[list[9],list[12],list[16]]

#if c1,c2,c3,c4 are unique
#do something
```

How can I compare that those 4 lists are unique?

Comment: Don't shadow built-ins. Use a sensible variable name like `lst` or `L`, **not** `list`. Also, define unique precisely. Does order matter? Or is `['r', 'b', 'r']` equivalent to `['b', 'r', 'r']`?

Comment: So desired output is what?

Comment: @jpp yes, but I used 'list' just as an example. and no, order does not matter

Comment: @U9-Forward to return an error message if at least two those lists are similar(have the same elements, no matter the order)

Comment: @Plagga OKay then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *unique* you mean *don't contain identical values in each position*, then something like this should work:

```
if len(set(map(tuple, [c1, c2, c3, c4]))) == 4:
  # All four lists are unique
```

Note that in this scenario, `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are distinct.  If, for your purposes those would be the same, then you'd want this instead:

```
if len(set(map(frozenset, [c1, c2, c3, c4]))) == 4:
  # All four lists are unique
```

If you need some other definition of *unique* then you need to be more clear in what you're asking.

Comment: order doesn't matter, I should have been more precise. using frozenset works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since order doesn't matter, you may want to sort the sub lists and then check if a set of those has the same length as the original list of sorted lists:

```
ordered = [tuple(sorted(l)) for l in [c1, c2, c3, c4]]
# [('f', 'l', 't'), ('f', 'r', 't'), ('b', 'r', 't'), ('b', 'l', 't')]

unique = len(set(ordered)) == len(ordered)
# True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if max(len(c1), len(c2)) != len(set(c1) & set(c2))\
        and max(len(c1), len(c3)) != len(set(c1) & set(c3))\
        and max(len(c1), len(c4)) != len(set(c1) & set(c4))\
        and max(len(c2), len(c3)) != len(set(c2) & set(c3))\
        and max(len(c3), len(c4)) != len(set(c3) & set(c4)):
    print("Do something.")
else:
    print("Do something else.")
```

Comment: Fails on `c1 = ['a','b','b']; c2 = ['a', 'b', 'b']`

Answer (score -1):

I am usually not a fan of one liners, but I believe this should work:

```
if (tuple(c1) != tuple(c2) != tuple(c3) != tuple(c4)):
    print 'All are unique!'
else:
    raise 'Oh no, they are not all unique!'
```

Comment: Fails on `c1 = list('aab'); c2 = list('abb')`

Comment: You can't call the list object on a string as you did, and no, my code should work for those cases if you use sets like I did.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that OP had been shadowing builtins. Nevertheless, your code fails on the use case I demonstrated, which is not  exactly an obscure edge case.

Comment: `set(['a','a','b']) != set(['a','b','b'])` evaluates to `False` even though the two sets are unique to eachother.

Comment: Ah great point! Sorry, misinterpreted what you meant at first.

Comment: Updated to use tuple structures instead, logically it should work now. Let me know if you still have a concern.